# Can't select item using own layout with ListActivity

Tags: android, listactivity

I was trying out a `ListActivity` example from the net. I am having problem using a custom list layout. Here is my code:

```
public class Test1Activity extends ListActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };
    //ArrayAdapter<String> standard_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

    ArrayAdapter<String> my_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mylistlayout, R.id.label,values);
    setListAdapter(my_adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
```

`onListItemClick` is working fine when I use the standard adapter. But it doesn't work when use my adapter. In fact I don't even see any highlighting when I click on the list items. Why is this happening. Am I missing some code?

`mylistlayout` is a simple `LinearLayout` with a `TextView`(id `label`) and a `Button`(id `button1`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="287dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="items" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:text="X" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

to your `Button` in the xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this attribute to your LinearLayout of your `mylistlayout`:

`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`